# replace series data with blanks

Tags: pandas

How do I remove the repetitive values from a column?

The expected output is attached (in excel format)

[image: state code should be modified]

The State column has 4 values for "West Bengal". Only the first one should be displayed.

Comment: Sorry are you saying that when bring this into pandas that you have 4 duplicated rows with 'West Bengal'? Have you tried `df.drop_duplicates('State')`?

Comment: Aside from display reasons why do you want to replace with blank, is it just so that when you export it back to xls you get the display you want?

Comment: drop duplicates will complete remove those rows. I need to keep the rest of the data and remove only repetitive cells from one column. This will be used for generating reports in specified format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) to detect when the rows change value, we can then use the boolean mask to set these rows to blank:

```
In [52]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'state':['West Bengal','West Bengal','West Bengal', 'East','East'] , 'amount':[14,25,36,47,58]}) 
df
Out[52]:
   amount        state
0      14  West Bengal
1      25  West Bengal
2      36  West Bengal
3      47         East
4      58         East
In [54]:

df.loc[df['state'] == df['state'].shift(), 'state'] = ''
df
Out[54]:
  amount        state
0     14  West Bengal
1                    
2                    
3     47         East
4
```

Comment: Add an amount column to dataframe and your solution will remove the entire row and not just state. 
pd.DataFrame({'state':['West Bengal','West Bengal','West Bengal', 'East','East'] , 'amount':[14,25,36,47,58]})

Comment: I need to keep the amount values in the above example even if state is blank (i.e. continued from above)

Comment: This is correct. Isn't there a method for this? like ffill or bfill ?

Comment: Not really as you are not replacing `NaN` values or resampling. You're essentially detecting a change in values but that itself is a custom client condition

Comment: Sorry typo in a previous comment, should be :`df.loc[df['state'] == df['state'].shift(), 'state'] = ''`